# how to call method in service in android

Tags: android, service

I have created a service for TweetCollectorService. I want to call a method of another class in my service.can I do this Plz Help me.

Thankyou

Comment: elaborate more where does your class exists?

Comment: when my service is run then I called Activity,but I want to call Method of this activity So how can I call It???

Comment: for Activity I have called Intent i = new Intent(TweetCollectorService.this, StatusListActivity.class);
                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 startActivity(i);  but I want to call method of this activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.. Only difference here is the method execution also occurs in background process.. No other difference..

Its not best practice to have other utility functions/methods in Activity, which mainly is to handle user interaction. so Strictly follow java convention and create different class which has all these methods, so it achieves cohesion.

You can dosomething like below..

```
 Class YourActivity extends Activity{

    public void do(){

    // do your task
    }
```

and in service just say `new YourActivity().do()`
}

Comment: so what I have to write for that

Comment: for activity I am using like this way...Intent i = new Intent(TweetCollectorService.this, StatusListActivity.class);
                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 startActivity(i);

Comment: Sorry But I cannot create static method so need some solution for only public class which is Void type

Comment: @Tarishi.. will that help.... see my edits.. and better get some knowledge about java prior to jumping in to development.. an advice..:)

Comment: yaa I have seen @ntc.Is it not possible to call my public method in service class,because i am not able to change the type if i will do this then it is effected in my whole app.plz try to understand

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can able to call the other class method. If you using your custom class then create the method as static so no need to create object of that class

suppose your custom class which extend Activity or not then also you can do like this way.

```
class CustomClass extends Activity{
     public static void mymethod(){
        // call me
     }
}
```

now you can call into the service like this way without creating any object as explicitly

```
class MyService extends Service{
    onCreate(){
        CustomClass.mymethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting properly plz elaborate your answer

Comment: my Class Is an activity that is main Activity I have to use method of my activity

Comment: method you want use is it static method?

Comment: No i am not able to create my method Static,It is only public so plz give me some other solutions

Comment: in your case I think there is not other way. bcoz if you implement using Intent then it will start new activity.